# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

```
**Getting error -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')**
Code is there on JSFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/gLt40fry/1/

I want display data from Airtable to Datatable using AJAX

var ajaxData = $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'localhost',
        success:function(response){
            ajaxData = response.records
            
            console.log(ajaxData)
        }
    })
```

Datatable must show the content from Airtable API inside table. Table is using Datatable and the code is available on JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/gLt40fry/1/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing data before it is loaded from API. Use Promise instead.

```
Add code implementation after api data is received.    
https://jsfiddle.net/7c69k5rm/1/
```

Code:

```
var getData = () =>  {
 return $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'https://api.airtable.com/v0/appcn5JFxBMUeiYzA/lab-report?api_key=keyqyBQVPg55QG4kA',
        success:function(response){
            ajaxData = response.records
            
        //  console.log(ajaxData)
        }
    });
}

getData().then(ajaxData => {
 console.log(ajaxData.records);

var dataSet = [];

for (let i = 0; i < ajaxData.records.length; i++) {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(ajaxData.records[i].fields.Date_of_Manufacturing);
    arr.push(ajaxData.records[i].fields.Batch);
    arr.push(ajaxData.records[i].fields.Product);
    
    dataSet.push(arr);
}

console.log(dataSet);

});
```

Comment: What do u mean by that?. Can u make change to code on https://jsfiddle.net/7c69k5rm/1/

Comment: I already made changes. Please see updated url on the comment.

Comment: Which url? In my sfiddle.net/7c69k5rm/1 it is not working

Comment: Your code is not working. Data is not coming inside Datatable